# Ionic CLI break with Internet connection

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am facing a problem in ionic to start a new ionic project or serve ionic project while Internet connection in on.
In Command Prompt no error come but CLI break after a few seconds. But without an Internet connection it works perfectly, mean without an Internet connection I can serve the ionic project (ionic serve). But to start a new project we have to connect our laptop to the Internet connection and with the connection, I have this problem. I have reinstalled the ionic but still, I'm facing this problem.

This is the image of process of `ionic serve` with Internet connection

[image: ionic serve output]

Comment: what does `ionic info` give?

Comment: E:\experiment>ionic serve
[INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 -
       Ctrl+C to cancel
[17:16:29]  watch started ...
[17:16:29]  build dev started ...

E:\experiment>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!
first we have to uninstall ionic

**npm uninstall -g ionic cordova**

still ionic has not completely uninstalled. To do the same we have to delete all ionic files in our windows drive (Local Disk :c).

then we have to uninstall nodejs from control panel.

still node and npm has not uninstalled completely so we also have to delete all node and npm files from c drive.

now install **nodejs recommended** and the ionic

**npm install -g ionic cordova**

It will work now....

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't start up. You should get a lot more processes showing after the

```
webpack started ...
```

like sass, postprocess, lint, build etc.

To find out the possible error you can use the verbose switch which may help show what the error is.

```
$ ionic serve --verbose
```

Please try that and see what the output is.